# TableView heightForRowAtIndexPath returning incorrect section

Tags: swift, swift2, tableview

I have a static table view with 16 sections. When I attempt to modify the height in heightForRowAtIndexPath, the "section" of indexPath is returning a number from 0 to 3, instead of an expected 0 to 15. Below is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    print("Section: \(indexPath.section), Row: \(indexPath.row)")
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return heightArray![indexPath.section]
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

}
```

It's printing the following:

```
Section: 0, Row: 0
Section: 0, Row: 1
Section: 0, Row: 2
Section: 1, Row: 0
Section: 1, Row: 1
Section: 2, Row: 0
Section: 2, Row: 1
Section: 2, Row: 2
Section: 3, Row: 0
Section: 3, Row: 1
Section: 0, Row: 0
Section: 0, Row: 1
Section: 0, Row: 2
Section: 1, Row: 0
Section: 1, Row: 1
Section: 2, Row: 0
Section: 2, Row: 1
Section: 2, Row: 2
Section: 3, Row: 0
```

What's going on?

**EDIT**

Here's what's going on when I scroll up and down...

[image: Screen recording of simulator and console]

Storyboard screenshot (there clearly are 16 sections here):
[image: storyboard]

EDIT

Here's what's showing up incorrectly. This is section #4. It's not formatting how I expect it to format to in the heightForRowAtIndexPath. Note that M03 is formatting OK (cell #0 of that section is the right height). M04 and after are formatting incorrectly. I'm setting the values in "heightArray" in viewDidAppear and am trying to use those heights in tableView.reloadData().

**EDIT**
Here's my ViewDidAppear Method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true



    textViewArray = [m1DF,m2DF,m3DF,m4DF,m5DF,m6DF,m7DF,m8DF,m9DF,m10DF,m11DF,m12DF,m13DF,m14DF,m15DF,m16DF]
    print("*****1*****\n\n\n\n\n \(m1DF.bounds.height), \(m1DF.frame.height)")

    for (index, tv) in textViewArray!.enumerate() {

        let fixedWidth = tv.frame.size.width
        tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        let newSize = tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        var newFrame = tv.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        tv.frame = newFrame;
        heightArray[index] = newSize.height
        print("Row \(index) has height \(newSize.height)")


    }

    print(heightArray)


    for (index, _) in (heightArray.enumerate()) {
        heightArray[index] = textViewArray![index].frame.height

    }

    print(heightArray)

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Did you continue scrolling down?

Comment: @ozgur Yes, I did...that's all that it printed.

Comment: can you show your cellForRowAtIndexPath and the storyboard for this table

Comment: @jo3birdtalk I don't have a cellForRowAtIndexPath override method -- my TV data is straight from the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This method has to return 16:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return someValue // as you note you have 16 sections, this number has to have 16 in its value
    }
```

Comment: I implemented this method but it didn't fix the issue. The console still prints 0, 1, 2, and 3 only.

Comment: But in the animation you added, I see number much higher than 3. (e.g. Section: 13) Or honestly I don't understand your issue.

Comment: when I run the code and scroll in the console, it only prints lines for sections 0 to 3 and updates those sections. For some reason it ignores everything past section 3 until I scroll down in the SIMULATOR/app, and then it prints the remaining sections but doesn't update the storyboard accordingly to my code.

Comment: If you are guessing, why your console shows only some sections at a time, it's common UITableView's behaviour, as it renders only those sections and rows, that are visible at current moment. Or please, try to explain your animated GIF once again to be more clear, what you miss, as I consider that behaviour running OK

Comment: Basically it's not rendering cells after section 4 as I would expect it to. The stuff in my heightForRowAtIndexPath isn't evident  for cells after section 4, even after I scroll down in the table view.

Comment: what you mean by rendering cells? or "expect it to". the console print is showing sections above 4.

Comment: @AlbertGhar Is you tableView showing what you need? If not, what do you expect. Let's try not to mix it with console output first.

Comment: @jo3birdtalk edited my question to include a screenshot.

Comment: @AlbertGhar Well place the code, where you set cell heights in your viewDidAppear method, please.

Comment: My code to set the value of the heights - heightArray - is in viewdidappear, but I'm setting the actual heights to those values in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @AlbertGhar So could you post this viewDidAppear interpretation of your height establishment?

Comment: Posted the viewDidAppear method above.